# Is there any way to set default Font face for RichText editor in android

Tags: android, text-editor, rich-text-editor, richtext

Is there any way to set default Font face for Rich-text editor in android, I am using "[jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android)" this plugin does not have font type feature. Has anyone used this plugin can somebody suggest me a plugin as per mentioned requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything what you want, but you could change fonts with this library https://github.com/kemallette/RichEditText